# Javascript: 'window' is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, but the following code has been giving me a lot of trouble:

```
window.onload = function () {
    for ( var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < seats.length; j++) {
            document.getElementById(getSeatId(i, j)).onclick = function(evt) {
                getSeatStatus(getSeatId(i, j));
            };
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("search").onclick = findSeat;
    document.getElementById("male_search").onclick = findMaleSeats;
    initSeats();
};
```

It is from an external JS file and it is the only file linked to the page. `findSeat`, `findMaleSeats`, `getSeatId`, and `initSeats` are all defined a little bit later in the file. When I double click this file, I get the following error:

> ```
> Windows Script Host
> Error: 'window' is not defined
> Code: 800A1391
> ```

I already tried moving the code to other places in the file, assigning a different function (even an empty function) to `window.onload` and many other things. It just seems that my computer doesn't know what `window` is. And if I try to open the HTML in a browser the nothing loads (as one would expect).

Does someone know what is wrong with this?

Comment: Unrelated but WHY do you use IE to learn JavaScript? It is the worst JS environment you can have and their developer tools are sub-par compared to the ones other browsers have.

Comment: You're running this script in a browser, right? It almost sounds like your JavaScript is being interpreted as VBScript, from the looks of the error message.

Comment: Apparently not "It just seems that my computer doesn't know what window is. And if I try to open the HTML in a browser..."

Comment: Wow are you guys here at javascript always that fast? Anyway, thanks a bunch for the help that was really the problem. I even feel kind of embarassed for asking such a stupid (now that I see the answer) question. And btw, I 'm/was not using IE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It is from an external js file and it is the only file linked to the page.

OK.

> When I double click this file I get the following error

Sounds like you're double-clicking/running a .js file, which will attempt to run the script outside the browser, like a command line script. And that would explain this error:

`Windows Script Host Error: 'window' is not defined Code: 800A1391`

... not an error you'll see in a browser. And of course, the browser is what supplies the `window` object.

**ADDENDUM**: As a course of action, I'd suggest opening the relevant **HTML file** and taking a peek at the console. If you don't see anything there, it's likely your `window.onload` definition is simply being hit *after* the browser fires the `window.onload` event.

Answer (score 36):

The window object represents an open window in a browser. Since you are not running your code within a browser, but via Windows Script Host, the interpreter won't be able to find the window object, since it does not exist, since you're not within a web browser.

Comment: OK we understand what it does, but how to go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 14):

Trying to access an undefined variable will throw you a `ReferenceError`.

A solution to this is to use `typeof`:

```js
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  console.log("Oops, `window` is not defined")
}
```

or a try catch:

```
try { window } catch (err) {
  console.log("Oops, `window` is not defined")
}
```

While `typeof window` is probably the cleanest of the two, the try catch can still be useful in some cases.

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the original question? Older answers (such as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14164607)) have already answered the issue that the original poster was asking.