# Why is window sometimes undefined when using Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I've set a variable on window..

```
// index.html in a script tag
window.foo = 123;
```

I've imported this module into several other modules...
These modules use `window.foo`

```
// navigation.js
import myModule from 'my-module.js';
// footer.js
import myModule from 'my-module.js';
```

sometimes this loads `123` fine, and other times `window is not defined`.

What causes Webpack to sometimes not have access to window?

Comment: What did you do in the mean time? It shouldn't behave inconsistently.

Comment: I ended up putting window ref in a function so it is not called but once

Comment: are you executing web pack from command line?

Comment: Can you verify your case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164505/javascript-window-is-not-defined

Comment: In general, it should be something that your function has a parameter named `window`, which shadowed the global `window`. Because the global `window` is to some extent immutable. Even if you write `window = undefined` in the global scope, `window` still points to a `Window` instance.