# Ava+Sinon unite testing. ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, sinon, ava

I tried to write a test file to test one of the moduel. The module has a line of code that access `window.location.origin` which is causing an error when running the unit test : `ReferenceError: window is not defined.`

The moduel under test and test case code:

myfile.js:

```
const isExternal =  window.location.origin.includes('.com');

const getAccess = () => {
    if(isExternal){
        //Do somthing
    }
}
```

myfile.test.js:

```
const test = require('ava');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const myfile = require('../../src/myfile');

test.serial('test myfile', t => {
    myfile.isExternal = true;
    //Assert below
})
```

My problem is when I have the line  `const myfile = require('../../src/myfile');` in the code and run `npm run test`, it will show an error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
tests\myfile.test.js exited with a non-zero exit code: 1
```

Comment: Window only exists in the browser, so if you're running tests not in a browser you'll have to mock it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: 'window' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164505/javascript-window-is-not-defined)

Comment: Why are you trying to access `window.location.origin` in node.js?

Comment: @JaredSmith Can you show me code how to mock window?

Comment: @JaredSmith The js code is done by other developer which I am not allow to change it. Is that a way I can make it work by editing test file?

Comment: `global.window = { location: { origin: 'whatever' } };` or there are a million libraries, just search on npm.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for helping. But the moment I import myfile.js to the myfile.test.js like : const myfile = require('../../src/myfile'); It will give error. The Mock part not even called.

Comment: Yeah, that's because you have an undeclared variable reference. You'll have to mock window *before* requiring that module.

Comment: @JaredSmith OMG! Thank you so much! I added global['window'] = { location: { origin: 'whatever' } };  before const myfile = require('../../src/myfile');  Now the test case is working !! You just saved my career!!

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for helping. Do you mind I ask one more question: I tried to mock the `myfile.isExternal = false;` in one of the test case. Seems like it is always true. Do you know this by any chance?